# react-native versions not available in gradle

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to sync my android project w/ gradle - this project already worked fine and now I keep getting messages like 
Could not find com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.9

I tried using all the official versions from [the releases list](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases) and I always get the error above (while referring to the version I specify)

Any idea if something is maybe off with the repository?

Comment: What's your gradle file? That could help us spot the problem, might be a missing repository

Comment: @Thomas__ - thanks for the tip, see my answer below - problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Thomas__ thanks for the tip - the dependency for react-native was referencing

`maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android" }`,
my build script failed and `node-modules` wasn't created.

I needed to run `npm i react-native`